# Definitions of one-to-many, many-to-many etc

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a database application using Doctrine2. I'm getting somewhat confused by the foreign key mappings. I'm wondering, have I got these examples correct:

`One-To-One:` An `X` has exactly one `Y`.

`One-To-Many:` An `X` can have multiple `Y`s.

`Many-To-One:` Multiple `X`s can have the same `Y`.

`Many-To-Many:` Multiple `X`s can have multiple `Y`s.

This is the specific situation that got me confused:
A `User` has exactly one `HomeTown`. Many users can belong to the same home town, so the link for the `User` is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="HomeTown", inversedBy="localUsers")
 */
$homeTown;
```

And, the corresponding `HomeTown` link is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="homeTown")
 */
$localUsers;
```

OR is it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="homeTown")
 */
$localUsers;
```

Some clarification would be much appreciated!

I've been looking at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `OneToMany` association, the inverted has to be `ManyToOne`. Saying that, your second option is correct.

TIP: Using Doctrine CLI command `orm:validate-schema` might also help to identify  this issue.

The full path in Symfony app: `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Comment: Thanks! The more I thought about it, the more I thought that was the case. Thanks for the CLI tip too. For others: If you're using symfony2, the command is: `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`.

Comment: Great! I've updated my response with your full path command for Symfony. It's good tip!

Answer (score 1):

If you want one city to have many users the mapping should be as it follows

```
Entity City
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="homeTown")
 */
private $users;
...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
...

Entity User
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORm\JoinColumn(name="home_town", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $homeTown;
```

This mapping shows us that the City which is owning side has On-To-Many relation with User(target Entity). Respectively the User which is inversed side has to be annotated with ManyToOne relation because many users have same city. Of course, here the target entity should be City. Its important to specify which column is pointing the foreignkey with the referencedColumnName attribute in JoinColumn annotation. It shows what column of other table points this key. In this example in table User there is column named "home_town" which is a foreign key pointing to column id of table City

In ManyToOne relation you shod use JoinColumn annotation

This mapping is also Bidirectional.

You can make id Unidirectional as in the User Entity do not use "inversedBy=" attribute and remove OneToMany annotation with $user property from the City entity. It is something like when you have to know the city of a particular user, but you do not need to know all users for a specific city